# Unable to connect to server using my public ip address

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

I have written a simple chat application in Java and its working perfectly fine when i am trying to connect to server using "127.0.0.1" i.e from within the system.
But when i am trying to connect to server using my public ip address,the client is not able to locate socket?How to solve it.
Here is the client code

```
    String ipadd = "213.109.45.23";
    InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName(ipadd);
    sockfd = new Socket(ip,1800);
```

Here is the server code

```
    String ipadd = "0.0.0.0";
    InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName(ipadd);
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket();
    ss.setReuseAddress(true);
    ss.bind(new InetSocketAddress(ip,1800));
```

Comment: Show us some code maybe? Also just going off what you have said.... you might need to port forward?

Comment: This is more likely a firewall issue than a programming one.

Comment: Make sure to go into your routers settings and set up port forwarding.

Comment: @3kings  I am using ubuntu...can you just tell me how to port forward?

Comment: You might have bounded the server socket to a local address. If you post the code we might be more helpful.

Comment: @Victor I posted the code

Comment: Your port forwarding is done via your Router's administrative page. It is not entirely platform dependent :).. Please expand on what type or router you have as well as some code to show us what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: the code seems to be correct. I think this is more a connectivity problem. two things to check: firewall and routing. You can start by checking if the client can reach the server, ping and nmap should be useful.